# Well, I have a urdf, mesh(stl files), manifest file, display.launch and gazebo.launch files

Tags: ros, gazebo, urdf, solidworks, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, I have a urdf, mesh(stl files), manifest file, display.launch and gazebo.launch files. What do i need to do next to launch my robot in gazebo or atleast spawn it in gazebo. Tutorials are helpless till now. Do i need to make a catkin_ws or some package or something....please help... This maybe basic but i am new to ROS and even LINUX. I would appreciate if everything is explained in detail starting from very basics. I have installed ROS indigo and gazebo.

My files can be viewed from this link:

http://www.megafileupload.com/eo8y/Assem1.rar (click on free user slow download, its rar and my assembly name is Assem1)

Thankyou

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225361/well,-i-have-a-urdf,-mesh(stl-files),-manifest-file,-display.launch-and-gazebo.launch-files./) by [Shoiab](https://answers.ros.org/users/25559/shoiab/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-01-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Building%20a%20Visual%20Robot%20Model%20with%20URDF%20from%20Scratch

http://answers.ros.org/question/187815/how-do-i-display-my-own-urdf-in-rviz/

---

Originally posted by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) with karma: 406 on 2016-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1